By geo coordinates, knowing the coordinates of the tile, find the coordinates of the pixel in the tile
Suppose we have a point (-43.7927620; 172.9539540):
location: Takamatua Hill
lat: -43.7927620
lon: 172.9539540
osm: https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/10680066993#map=17/-43.793139/172.953628
Let's say Z(zoom) will be 15, so the tile for this point will be like this:
osmtile: https://tile.openstreetmap.org/15/32126/20826.png
X: 32126
Y: 20826
Z: 15
If I open this tile in a graphical editor, I can easily determine the pixel coordinates. Because the tile size is 256 pixels along the axis. The origin is in the upper left corner,
then the pixel coordinate for the given point will be ~
X:167
Y:189
I got these values by simply placing the cursor over the point "Takamatua Hill" in the graphics editor.
I want to learn how to get pixel coordinate values in a tile from javascript(or any other) code. Having a geo-coordinate, the zoom of the desired tile.
Please help me solve this problem.

See https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Slippy_map_tilenames. It explains everything and contains code for various languages.
